# unable to output a large amount of values to a file through traversing a data structure (Binary Search Tree)

Tags: c, binary-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//structure that defines a binary search
//tree
struct BSTREE {
    long long int key;
    struct BSTREE *left;
    struct BSTREE *right;
};

//this function returns the root of the modified tree
struct BSTREE *insert(struct BSTREE *root, long long int num){
int exit=1;

struct BSTREE *temp = root;

//if tree is empty, return new node
if (root == NULL){
    struct BSTREE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct BSTREE));
    newNode->key = num;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    root = newNode;
    return root;
}
while(exit){
    if (num > temp->key)
    {

        //if reached end then create space
        if (temp->right == NULL){
        struct BSTREE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct BSTREE));
        newNode->key = num;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right=NULL;
        temp->right = newNode;
        exit = 0;
        } else
            temp = temp->right;
    }
    else
    {

        //if reached end then create space
        if (temp->left == NULL){
        struct BSTREE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct BSTREE));
        newNode->key = num;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right=NULL;
        temp->left = newNode;
        exit = 0;
        } else
            temp = temp->left;
    }
}
return root;

}

//this function performs an inorder traversal and
//prints out to the file specified
void inorderTraversal(struct BSTREE* root, FILE *fp) {
    //if not at the end of binary search tree
    if (root != NULL) {
        //go to left
        inorderTraversal(root->left, fp);

        //printing out the nodes to the file specified
        fprintf(fp, "%lld\n", root->key);

        //go to right
        inorderTraversal(root->right, fp);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct BSTREE *root = NULL;

    /*inserting a value
    root = insert(root, 15);
    root = insert(root, 800);
    root = insert(root, 32);
    */

    //part 2: insert numbers 1 to n into the binary search
    //tree.
    long long int n =50000;
```

//the binary search tree structure cant seem to take too many values (from the algorithm below).  for some reason it kept //crashing when trying to reach to 50 000 but works well anything below it such as if n = 30 000. //The issue is revolving in between the clock functions where the for loop is inserting the //numbers I believe. I have tested it that it seems to work well but as it gets closer to 50 000 //for i. It seems to crash. Is there a way to allocate enough space for the structure to be able //to hand more values? (up to 100 000). The extra comments for insert was to test if there was an issue with the insert algorithm itself. but i couldnt find that to be the case. P.S. I have changed it to Iterative and it could hold more values -up to 42 000- but it still could not take in the required amount.

```
    //recording the time spent to build the data structure
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (long long int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        root = insert(root, i);
        if (i == 30000)
            printf("reached end\n");
    }

    printf("done for loop\n");

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double) (end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("The time spent building the data structure is %f\n", time_spent);

    //creating the file for the sorted values
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("sorted.txt", "w+");

    //runs the inorder traversal
    inorderTraversal(root, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Likely getting a stack overflow. Because your recursive algorithm's maximum stack depth is related to the number of nodes. Since you are inserting consecutive numbers it ends up being a long singly linked list which is the worst case max depth for a binary tree.

Comment: Keeping the tree balanced is most of the work when writing code for a BST. See for example, [AVL tree rebalancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Rebalancing) or [red-black tree insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree#Insertion).

Comment: I was told specifically to create a Binary search tree and not make it balanced. This is one of the main reasons it is confusing me also.

Comment: Did the requirements say you have to test with the worst case? If not then you should test with more realistic data such as random values. Sequential values are the absolute worst case. If you do need to deal with the worst case then you probably need to convert the recursive implementation into an iterative one.

Comment: the teacher said to test with the worst case first. adding 1..n in that order starting with n= 20 000 than 50 000 and so on.

Comment: Well then you probably can't use recursion. Change it to iterative.

Comment: how would changing from recursive to iterative make a difference though? isn't the main problem associated with the limit of the  stack depth and not the algorithm calling itself?

Comment: Every recursive call needs more stack space. That is, the amount of stack required is directly proportional to the depth of the recursion which is the same as the depth of the tree in your case (50000). An iterative solution would have a constant call depth (of 1) regardless of the depth of the tree.

Comment: For example, every time `inorderTraversal()` calls itself a complete function stack must be set up to handle the call. That will require at minimum space for a StackPointer, FramePointer and a pointer for `root` and `fp`. So say minimum of 32-bytes per-call. If you have a 1-Meg stack, you get 32K function calls before StackOverflow. (e.g. `1048576 / 32` -- which is why your professor suggested adding 1 from 20K to see where it quit)